# Windows cmd: 'java' command error

Tags: java, cmd

I am trying to open a program using Java.

I type `java prog_name`, yet it issues the following error:

> Error: could not open `C:\ispLEVER_Classic2_0\ispcpld\lib\jvm.cfg'

*ispLEVER* is another program installed on my computer. It's unrelated to Java.
Even the folder: `C:\ispLEVER_Classic2_0\ispcpld\lib` doesn't exist.

Can you, please, suggest me a solution to the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First I would try to find out where your java is (full file path) and than I would try to run the program using the full java path. If this works fine you could try to figure out why ispLEVER messed up with the  default location of java.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I've tried running the program using the full path.It doesn't work (same error)

Comment: Are you sure `java` installed properly? Can you just check typing only `java` in your command window and see that works? this should not show `command not found`.. It would be more helpful if you share more information about your issue..

Comment: @Sridhar I typed 'java'. It's the same error: Error: could not open `C:\ispLEVER_Classic2_0\ispcpld\lib\jvm.cfg'

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. I will reinstall Java. (though the error seems interesting)

Comment: what is the result for `java -version` ? if this too does not work, something wrong either in the java installation or  in your system..

Comment: @Sridhar No, it doesn't work. I guess there is something wrong with installation. Thank you.